# How to make variables accessible across multiple get requests in express? And is there a better way to code this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, knex.js

I have the following get request where I call a bunch of data and pass it through to my EJS view.

```
router.get('/currentrentals', ensureAuthenticated,  async (req, res) => {

const companies = await Company.getCompanies();
const barges = await Barge.getBarges();
const parishes = await Parish.getParishes();
const states = await State.getStates();
const pickupdropoff = await PickupDropoff.getPickupDropoff();
var notifications = await Notification.getNotifications();
JSON.stringify(barges);
JSON.stringify(companies);
JSON.stringify(parishes);
JSON.stringify(states);
JSON.stringify(pickupdropoff);
JSON.stringify(notifications);
var notifications =  await notifications.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id).slice(0,3);

res.render('currentrentals', {
    name: req.user.name, companies: companies, barges: barges, parishes: parishes, states: states, pickupdropoff : pickupdropoff, notifications : notifications
});
}
);
```

Two questions:

1. I have multiple get requests that requires the same information.  Is there a way to make this data available across the entirety of my site, so I don't have to rewrite this for each get path?
2. Is there a more succinct way to write the existing code I have?  Perhaps looping through them or something of the sort?  Simply for learning purposes.

The code currently works as-is.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your questions, but I think that your `JSON.stringify` statements have no effect, as you're ignoring the returned values.

Comment: That is helpful indeed though as part of the question was how to simplify!  Could you elaborate why I would be ignoring them?  Is it because I have to assign the stringified values to a variable, then pass that to the render?

Comment: If you want to make use of the stringified value, you could indeed assign it to a variable or use it in an expression or function call.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Manfred.  I removed the stringify functions and it worked all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is constant, you can try this:

```
let data = null;

async function getData() {
  if (!data) {
    data = {
      companies: await Company.getCompanies(),
      barges: await Barge.getBarges();
      parishes: await Parish.getParishes(),
      states: await State.getStates(),
      pickupdropoff: await PickupDropoff.getPickupDropoff(),
      notifications: (await Notification.getNotifications()).sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id).slice(0,3)
    };
  }
  return data;
}

router.get('/currentrentals', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    res.render('currentrentals', { name: req.user.name, ...(await getData()) });
  }
);

// other routes
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting an "Unexpected identifier" at Company.getCompanies(), specifically Company.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I guess the problem is that [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) can only be used inside an async function.

Comment: IIRC node doesn't support top level await. In any case, this stuff should be in a function where it can be called from multiple routes.